# Quick blox chat message sending response is success but messages are not delivered to server

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

Just working with Quick blox Chat API though its interesting and fun but stuck horribly when coming to sending messages successfully to group.

I first created a ChatDialog(not public group) and its created with out any problems.Now i want to send messages to the ChatDialog.

This is the code at Client side in Swift :

```
    let user = QBUUser()
    user.ID = (QBSession.currentSession().currentUser?.ID)!
    user.password = "*********"
    QBChat.instance().connectWithUser(user) { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            print("Success in connection")
            self.chatGroup = QBChatDialog(dialogID:self.selectedChatGroup.chatGroupId, type: QBChatDialogType.Group)
            self.chatGroup.occupantIDs = self.selectedChatGroup.opponents
            self.chatGroup.joinWithCompletionBlock { (err) in
                if err == nil{
                    print("Joined Succesfully")
                    let message: QBChatMessage = QBChatMessage()
                    message.text = "PRAISE THE LORD"
                    message.deliveredIDs = [(QBSession.currentSession().currentUser?.ID)!]
                    message.readIDs = [(QBSession.currentSession().currentUser?.ID)!]
                    message.markable = true

                    self.chatGroup.sendMessage(message, completionBlock: { (error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if err == nil{
                            print(message.text)
                            print("Message sent Succesfully")

                            let resPage = QBResponsePage(limit:20, skip: 0)

                            QBRequest.messagesWithDialogID(self.selectedChatGroup.chatGroupId, extendedRequest: nil, forPage: resPage, successBlock: {(response: QBResponse, messages: [QBChatMessage]?, responcePage: QBResponsePage?) in

                                print("Messages count is \(messages?.count)")

                                }, errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse!) in

                            })

                        }else{
                            print(err?.localizedDescription)
                        }

                    });
                }
                else{
                    print(err?.localizedDescription)
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

This is the Response that i am getting back.i am pretty sure that logging to chat, connecting to group are successful. Even from the response given back from the API is also affirming that sending message is successful.But i am not able to see any messages in the Admin Panel at Quick blox. And also tried getting all the messages from the Chat dialog but its giving 0 messages.So my messages are not getting delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Yah, got the solution from Quickblox API.This is what i missed in my code.

```
    var params = NSMutableDictionary()
    params["save_to_history"] = true
    message.customParameters = params
```

Worked like a charm!